# Can't display all of given data in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I'm trying to display data from forecast api in RecyclerView. The thing is, I constantly getting just a single piece of data displayed - the first one from the api, but there should many more. I easily can log it by using simple for loop. I've already pretty much ran out of ideas what should be changed here... Could you please help me, somehow?

**MainActivity**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String BASE_URL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/";
    List<ModelClass> mTestData;
    ForecastAdapter mAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTestData = new ArrayList<>();

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.main_rv);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        mAdapter = new ForecastAdapter(mTestData);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        ApiInterface apiInterface = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);

        Call<ModelClass> getForecastData = apiInterface.getForecastData(36, 137, "api_key_here");
        getForecastData.enqueue(new Callback<ModelClass>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ModelClass> call, Response<ModelClass> response) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: "+response.code());

                mTestData = Collections.singletonList(response.body());
                mAdapter.setData123(mTestData);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ModelClass> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Adapter**

```
    public class ForecastAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ForecastAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<ModelClass> mForecastData = new ArrayList<>();
    private static final String TAG = "ForecastAdapter";

    public ForecastAdapter(List<ModelClass> mForecastData) {
        this.mForecastData = mForecastData;
    }

    public void setData123(List<ModelClass> data){
        this.mForecastData = data;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mTemperature.setText(String.valueOf(mForecastData.get(position).getForecastData().get(position)
        .getDatetime()));
        Log.i(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: "+mForecastData.get(position).getForecastData().get(position).getDatetime());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mForecastData.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView mTemperature, mPressure;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mTemperature = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_temperature);
            mPressure = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_pressure);
        }
    }
}
```

**Model class**

```
public class ModelClass {
    @SerializedName("cod")
    private int requestCode;
    @SerializedName("list")
    List<ForecastList> forecastData = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<ForecastList> getForecastData() {
        return forecastData;
    }


    public class ForecastList {
        @SerializedName("dt")
        private int datetime;
        @SerializedName("main")
        MainData mainData = null;

        public MainData getMainData() {
            return mainData;
        }

        public int getDatetime() {
            return datetime;
        }

        public class MainData {
            @SerializedName("temp")
            private double temperature;

            public double getTemperature() {
                return temperature;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**api interface**

```
  public interface ApiInterface {
    @GET("data/2.5/forecast?")
    Call<ModelClass> getForecastData(
            @Query("lat") int lat,
            @Query("lon") int lon,
            @Query("appid") String api_key);
}
```

**Example of json response**

```
{
  "cod": "200",
  "message": 0,
  "cnt": 40,
  "list": [
    {
      "dt": 1596564000,
      "main": {
        "temp": 293.55,
        "feels_like": 293.13,
        "temp_min": 293.55,
        "temp_max": 294.05,
        "pressure": 1013,
        "sea_level": 1013,
        "grnd_level": 976,
        "humidity": 84,
        "temp_kf": -0.5
      },
      "weather": [
        {
          "id": 500,
          "main": "Rain",
          "description": "light rain",
          "icon": "10d"
        }
      ],
      "clouds": {
        "all": 38
      },
      "wind": {
        "speed": 4.35,
        "deg": 309,
        "gust": 7.87
      },
      "visibility": 10000,
      "pop": 0.49,
      "rain": {
        "3h": 0.53
      },
      "sys": {
        "pod": "d"
      },
      "dt_txt": "2020-08-04 18:00:00"
    },

    ...

"city": {
    "id": 2643743,
    "name": "London",
    "coord": {
      "lat": 51.5073,
      "lon": -0.1277
    },
    "country": "GB",
    "timezone": 0,
    "sunrise": 1578384285,
    "sunset": 1578413272
  }
}
```

**MainActivity.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/main_rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**list_item.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_temperature"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:background="#bbbbbb"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_pressure"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="15dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**How I log the values from retrofit response**

```
for(ModelClass modelClass : mTestData){
                Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: "+modelClass.getForecastData().get(0).getDatetime());
                Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: "+modelClass.getForecastData().get(1).getDatetime());
                Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: "+modelClass.getForecastData().get(2).getDatetime());
            }
...
```

Output from console:

```
    2022-03-08 12:22:37.252 10032-10032/com.example.retrofittest I/ContentValues: onResponse: 1646740800
2022-03-08 12:22:37.252 10032-10032/com.example.retrofittest I/ContentValues: onResponse: 1646751600
2022-03-08 12:22:37.252 10032-10032/com.example.retrofittest I/ContentValues: onResponse: 1646762400
```

Comment: If you wanna log all you should not have get(0) , get(1), ... and so on but make a for or foreach or a while loop to log all. But... You did not answer my question: `Have you solved your problem?` In other words: Can you display all you want now?

Comment: I did not. Otherwise I would post the solution here.

Comment: Is that log output from `public void onResponse(Call<ModelClass> call, Response<ModelClass> response) {` or from your loop? Change it so it's different and you can see if that callback is happening. (the code is wrong in many levels though... making a network request in the onCreate of an activity is *bold*...

Answer (score 0):

Since you said "I easily can log it by using simple for loop" the data seems to be coming in just fine.

In my case the RecyclerView.ViewHolders layout file was the problem.
The height of the root viewGroup of list_item was match_parent. This should have been wrap_content.

Answer (score 0):

> > The thing is, I constantly getting just a single piece of data displayed

Yes. That is because `public int getItemCount()` returns the value 1 as that is the size of your ModelClass list: `return mForecastData.size()`.

You only get one ModelClass item from the webservice.

You better return something like:

```
return mForecastData.get(0).mTestData.size();
```

> > holder.mTemperature.setText(String.valueOf(mForecastData.get(position).getForecastData().get(position).getDatetime()));

Change to:

```
     holder.mTemperature.setText(String.valueOf(mForecastData.get(0).getForecastData().get(position).getDatetime()));
```

But that is not the temperature..

Comment: `mForecastData.size()` Your naming could be done betetr: `modelClassList.size()`

Comment: Sorry, but according to your code: return mForecastData.get(0).mTestData.size(); How I may approach this? I mean for me it looks like you want to get a list size which is nested in another list. mTestData is in MainActivity, mForecastData is in Adapter, these are two different lists. Sorry for my code tho. We all were starting somewhere, and I'm pretty new here also.

Comment: Have you at least tried what i suggested? And the first list has only one item as the webservice only returns one., It is unclear why you made a list for it if you receive only one item.

Answer (score 0):

You create an activity, then make a network request, and a callback ultimately is invoked and you send the results to a RecyclerView adapter. You claim the recyclerview is not displaying the items.

Potential problems.

1. The RecyclerView Layout and/or its View Holders are wrong (in XML).
2. The Adapter is not correctly coded.
3. The NetworkRequest is wrong/failing
4. The code is incorrectly put together and things are not happening in the order you expect.

I'd say you can isolate 1 and 2 quite easily.

Instead of making the network request, create a simple class (note: I'll use kotlin for brevity):

```
class FakeDataRepository {
  fun getData(): List<ModelClass> = listOf(...) //TODO: create a couple of fake/hardcoded items pretending they come from the API
}
```

Now instead of calling retrofit, in your activity do

`result = FakeDataRepository().getData()`

and then pass `result` to your adapter.

If your RecyclerView is fine, this should be displayed... if not, then you ought to see why.

Then if that's fixed, now start debugging when/how you receive the data; using the debugger, inspect the values inside your callbacks; is the adapter being called with the correct data?

And start from there.